# can i export svg from bonsaijs to png

Tags: svg, jquery-svg, bonsaijs

Using bonsaijs, is there a way to export the stage (or entire svg) to a png file ?

I saw an option for importing a svg, but couldn't find an easy way to export it. Any leads on this would be appreciated ?

Comment: There isn't official API available for creating a screenshot of the stage within the Runner-Context, like `stage.screenshot("png")`. Could you give some more details about your use-case, please?

Comment: @basecode So, on the client side (browser), user can create these circles and connect them with lines. I want to provide a URL to the user which would essentially represent whatever user has "drawn" as an image.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any API provided to export SVG to PNG.

Nevertheless you could either create your own exporter that draws the whole SVG context to a Canvas context and exports that as PNG or instead of storing a static image and losing all movie informations and interactivity you could possibly store the whole Bonsai-Script for that specific user.